Proof of the equivalence between Triebel Spaces and Bessel Potential
I've encountered a question regarding the relationship between Triebel-Lizorkin spaces and Bessel potential spaces. Specifically, I understand that
$F^s_{p,2} = H^{s,p}$, for $p \in (1,\infty)$.
However, I'm trying to comprehend the proof of this equality. I referred to the resource at http://www.math.ac.cn/kyry/hcc/teach/201912/P020200428625504254918.pdf, specifically Chapter 6. But Theorem 6.5.5 just states that it "obviously follows" from the result of the Littlewood-Paley decomposition equivalence for the $L^p$ norm.
I don't fully understand how this works. For the Besov spaces, the general case is typically handled using multiplier theorems, but for the Triebel-Lizorkin spaces, I am unsure how to derive the bound I obtain through the annulus combined with the differential order to $2^s$. This estimate needs to somehow work pointwise, but I am unclear on the details.
